# button value in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$('.next').click(function(){
    var buttonVal = document.querySelector('input[name="quiz"]:checked').value;
    alert(buttonVal);
})
```

So this works, but I'd like to see how does the syntax look in jQuery.

When I click this button with a class *next* and in alert I get notified what is the value of the radio button.

I tried writing the function in jQuery in many ways, but the alert is always `[Object object]`. Its not that big of an issue, since it works, but I am stubborn like that and can't solve it on my own.

Comment: $('input[name="quiz"]:checked').val()  ?

Comment: Please show us what you wrote in jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.next').click(function(){
    var buttonVal = $('input[name="quiz"]:checked')).val();
    alert(buttonVal);
});
```

Comment: how do you get `option` tag when OP was looking for `input`?

Comment: Oh sorry I thought its dropdown. I am going to correct same.

Comment: Code-only answers are auto-flagged as low quality and as such are discouraged on stackoverflow. In the future please embellish your answer with details and explain why it is a solution to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This code can also help

```
 $('body').on(".next","click",function(){
    var buttonVal = $('input[name="quiz"]:checked')).val();
    alert(buttonVal);
  });
```